# Can someone explain how to fix the error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, so I found an open source script for Unity and it kinda don't want to be friends with the new input system. I have no idea how to replace `InputActionAssetReference`

If somebody helps - thank you. The errors are: `Assets\Input\InputMaster.cs(7,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InputActionAssetReference' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and `Assets\Input\InputMaster.cs(50,26): error CS0115: 'InputMaster.MakePrivateCopyOfActions()': no suitable method found to override`

I'd really like the help because I want to use this 2D platformer controller. The script:

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


[Serializable]
public class InputMaster : InputActionAssetReference
{
    public InputMaster()
    {
    }
    public InputMaster(InputActionAsset asset)
        : base(asset)
    {
    }
    [NonSerialized] private bool m_Initialized;
    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Player
        m_Player = asset.GetActionMap("Player");
        m_Player_Movement = m_Player.GetAction("Movement");
        m_Player_Jump = m_Player.GetAction("Jump");
        m_Player_Dash = m_Player.GetAction("Dash");
        m_Player_Interact = m_Player.GetAction("Interact");
        m_Player_AttackA = m_Player.GetAction("Attack A");
        m_Initialized = true;
    }
    private void Uninitialize()
    {
        if (m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface != null)
        {
            Player.SetCallbacks(null);
        }
        m_Player = null;
        m_Player_Movement = null;
        m_Player_Jump = null;
        m_Player_Dash = null;
        m_Player_Interact = null;
        m_Player_AttackA = null;
        m_Initialized = false;
    }
    public void SetAsset(InputActionAsset newAsset)
    {
        if (newAsset == asset) return;
        var PlayerCallbacks = m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface;
        if (m_Initialized) Uninitialize();
        asset = newAsset;
        Player.SetCallbacks(PlayerCallbacks);
    }
    public override void MakePrivateCopyOfActions()
    {
        SetAsset(ScriptableObject.Instantiate(asset));
    }
    // Player
    private InputActionMap m_Player;
    private IPlayerActions m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface;
    private InputAction m_Player_Movement;
    private InputAction m_Player_Jump;
    private InputAction m_Player_Dash;
    private InputAction m_Player_Interact;
    private InputAction m_Player_AttackA;
    public struct PlayerActions
    {
        private InputMaster m_Wrapper;
        public PlayerActions(InputMaster wrapper) { m_Wrapper = wrapper; }
        public InputAction @Movement { get { return m_Wrapper.m_Player_Movement; } }
        public InputAction @Jump { get { return m_Wrapper.m_Player_Jump; } }
        public InputAction @Dash { get { return m_Wrapper.m_Player_Dash; } }
        public InputAction @Interact { get { return m_Wrapper.m_Player_Interact; } }
        public InputAction @AttackA { get { return m_Wrapper.m_Player_AttackA; } }
        public InputActionMap Get() { return m_Wrapper.m_Player; }
        public void Enable() { Get().Enable(); }
        public void Disable() { Get().Disable(); }
        public bool enabled { get { return Get().enabled; } }
        public InputActionMap Clone() { return Get().Clone(); }
        public static implicit operator InputActionMap(PlayerActions set) { return set.Get(); }
        public void SetCallbacks(IPlayerActions instance)
        {
            if (m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface != null)
            {
                Movement.started -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnMovement;
                Movement.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnMovement;
                Movement.cancelled -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnMovement;
                Jump.started -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnJump;
                Jump.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnJump;
                Jump.cancelled -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnJump;
                Dash.started -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnDash;
                Dash.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnDash;
                Dash.cancelled -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnDash;
                Interact.started -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnInteract;
                Interact.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnInteract;
                Interact.cancelled -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnInteract;
                AttackA.started -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnAttackA;
                AttackA.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnAttackA;
                AttackA.cancelled -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnAttackA;
            }
            m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface = instance;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                Movement.started += instance.OnMovement;
                Movement.performed += instance.OnMovement;
                Movement.cancelled += instance.OnMovement;
                Jump.started += instance.OnJump;
                Jump.performed += instance.OnJump;
                Jump.cancelled += instance.OnJump;
                Dash.started += instance.OnDash;
                Dash.performed += instance.OnDash;
                Dash.cancelled += instance.OnDash;
                Interact.started += instance.OnInteract;
                Interact.performed += instance.OnInteract;
                Interact.cancelled += instance.OnInteract;
                AttackA.started += instance.OnAttackA;
                AttackA.performed += instance.OnAttackA;
                AttackA.cancelled += instance.OnAttackA;
            }
        }
    }
    public PlayerActions @Player
    {
        get
        {
            if (!m_Initialized) Initialize();
            return new PlayerActions(this);
        }
    }
    private int m_KeyboardSchemeIndex = -1;
    public InputControlScheme KeyboardScheme
    {
        get

        {
            if (m_KeyboardSchemeIndex == -1) m_KeyboardSchemeIndex = asset.GetControlSchemeIndex("Keyboard");
            return asset.controlSchemes[m_KeyboardSchemeIndex];
        }
    }
    private int m_GamepadSchemeIndex = -1;
    public InputControlScheme GamepadScheme
    {
        get

        {
            if (m_GamepadSchemeIndex == -1) m_GamepadSchemeIndex = asset.GetControlSchemeIndex("Gamepad");
            return asset.controlSchemes[m_GamepadSchemeIndex];
        }
    }
}
public interface IPlayerActions
{
    void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
    void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
    void OnDash(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
    void OnInteract(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
    void OnAttackA(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
}
```

If there's too much to edit then can someone say what's the last supported version that has InputActionAssetReference?

Comment: It seems to me that you will need to find the superclass InputActionAssetReference.  You can try to remove it and rerun it though, but I doubt it would work. Is the input system missing the InputActionAssetReference class?

Comment: Okay instead of using InputActionAssetReference superclass try using IInputActionCollection to see if it works.

Comment: Restart Unity after doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited message --

I am replacing my answer without links as I have been told to. Basically instead of using InputActionAssetReference, another class like IInputActionCollection should be used. The first class must have been deprecated which is why it wasn't working properly.

Note: I have never used this new input system myself, but I am glad I was able to help! I get to learn something too which is a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

InputActionAssetReference was removed at release [0.2.8-preview] - 2019-4-23

> Generated wrapper code for Input Action Assets are now self-contained,
> generating all the data from code and not needing a reference to the
> asset; InputActionAssetReference has been removed.

[link to changelog](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/changelog/CHANGELOG.html?q=InputActionAssetReference)